# Como dejo fijo el numero de cuotas en un pago con la api de mercadopago en php

Tags: php, api, mercadopago

Estoy haciendo un *checkout* muy básico, y quiero dejar fijo en que solo se puede pagar en 1 cuota, ¿cómo hago eso? Yo pienso que es desde las preferencias, pero no se como. Así tengo las preferencias ahora:

```
$preference_data = array(
  "items" => array(
    array(
      "title" => "Multicolor kite",
      "quantity" => 1,
      "currency_id" => "ARS", // Available currencies at: https://api.mercadopago.com/currencies
      "unit_price" => 10
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera:

```
$preference_data = array(
  "items" => array(
    array(
      "title" => "Multicolor kite",
      "quantity" => 1,
      "currency_id" => "ARS", // Available currencies at: https://api.mercadopago.com/currencies
      "unit_price" => 10
    )
  ),
"payment_methods" => array(

        "installments" => 1
    )
);
```